# Вывод обьектов из массива

Tags: javascript

[image: Описание]

На вход в функцию прилетает объект. Я его обрабатываю, после чего получаю массив. Но вернуть из данной функции я должен не массив, а те объекты которые находятся в массиве. Проблема в том что из функции eventDataTransform выводится только первый элемент объекта, так как я возвращаю значение.

```
    eventDataTransform (data) {
      const arr = data.intervals.map(event => {
        return {
          start: data.date,
          title: event.from + '-' + event.to,
          from: event.from,
          to: event.to
        }
      })

      for (const obj of arr) {
        return obj
      }
    }
```

Comment: в чем проблема то? сделайте цикл по массиву, на каждой итерации цикла у вас будет объект.

Comment: Извините, неправильно задал вопрос)

Comment: вы сначала сделайте цикл, в итерациях вызывайте вашу функцию в которую передавайте объект.

Comment: eventDataTransform (data) {
      const arr = data.intervals.map(event => {
        return {
          start: data.date,
          title: event.from + '-' + event.to,
          from: event.from,
          to: event.to
        }
      })

      for (const obj of arr) {
        returnObj(obj)
      }

      function returnObj (item) {
        return item
      }
    }

Сделал так, теперь вообще ничего не возвращает.

Comment: можете еще привести конкретный массив с объектами.

Comment: {
        date: '2020-10-16',
        intervals: [
          {
            from: '11:00',
            to: '12:00'
          },
          {
            from: '13:00',
            to: '14:00'
          },
          {
            from: '14:00',
            to: '15:00'
          }
        ]
      }
Это объект который прилетает в мою функцию в параметр data.

Answer (score 2):

```js
const array = [{ id: 1, title: 'Title1'}, { id: 2, title: 'Title2' }]

array.forEach(obj => console.log(obj));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let arr = [{ date: '2020-10-16', intervals: [ { from: '11:00', to: '12:00' }, { from: '13:00', to: '14:00' }, { from: '14:00', to: '15:00' } ] }]
let eventDataTransform = (date, event) => {
  return {
    start: date,
    title: event.from + '-' + event.to,
    from: event.from,
    to: event.to
  }
}
  
let events = [];
arr.forEach(obj => {
    obj.intervals.forEach(event => {
    let transform_obj = eventDataTransform(obj.date, event);
    addedEventToCalendar(transform_obj); // тут с полученным объектов выполняем все нужные нам действия. 
  });
});

console.log(events);
```

Comment: Но мне на выход не нужен массив, только объекты.
Например:  {start: "2020-10-16", title: "11:00-12:00", from: "11:00", to: "12:00"} и остальные. Я это не могу сделать. И в параметр не массив идет в конкретно данном случае, а объект, который я выше скинул. Мне это нужно для того чтобы библиотека календаря принимала необходимые ей данные для отображения.

Comment: Обновил описание сверху. Может так понятнее)
Из меня тот еще объясняльщик)

Comment: Заместо добавления в массив, полученный объект передавайте в календарь.

Comment: В том то и дело что не уходят объекты, вернее первый только улетает(

Comment: Я подправил код, вы так же делаете?

Comment: Нет, это не совсем то что нужно. Я работаю только с функцией eventDataTransform. Она должна выводить объекты. И на вход падает, опять же, не массив а объект.

Comment: Добавил еще скриншотик. В общем короче не вывести из этой функции данные. Оно и понятно почему, из за того что когда возвращаем какое либо значение из нее то функция уже перестает дальше работать. А мне как то надо вывести несколько объектов. Вот в чем соль.

Comment: Дак для этого и нужны массивы

Comment: arr.forEach(obj => {
        obj.intervals.forEach(event => {
          const transformObj = eventDataTransform2(obj.date, event)
          return transformObj
        })
      })
Так не работает.

Comment: Если вам так не хочется в цикле прописывать дальнейшую логику работы с объектом, то создавайте новую функцию куда будете передавать готовый объект.

Comment: Опять же, не понимаю о чем вы. Вроде уже довольно подробно описал. Что значит не хочу прописывать дальнейшую логику в цикле? У меня и так есть цикл который получает нужные объекты, но ведь проблема в том что не могу вывести их из функции. И никакую новую функцию по идеи я не должен создавать. Для чего? Как мне это поможет вывести объекты из функции eventDataTransform? Может конечно я чего то не понимаю... Было бы намного понятнее если видеть то о чем вы говорите)